# Is it legal for credit card companies to terminate a credit card?

Tags: contract-law, california, loan, credit-card

The standard text of a credit card agreement implies American express can terminate the agreement at any time. Problem is, you already gave credit.

As an example, if I give someone a loan, I can't "take back" the loan. A line of credit is no different from a loan. If a customer has a line of credit of 10k, cashes it out, then Amex closes the card this should be the same as if they receive the credit and then the account closes before they cash it out.

If Amex was never intending to allow it to cash out and instead restricts the card before its ever used, this shows dishonesty.

Because a line of credit is money that is effectively already given to the customer, is it legal for Amex to close an account assuming they have no other legal reason and it's purely capricious behavior?

There was an answer citing a Supreme Court case with the answer no. This was deleted for some reason.

Comment: I can’t follow your question. What is “cashing out” a credit card? But yes, they can terminate it at any time.

Comment: "*if I give someone a loan, I can't "take back" the loan.*" Yes you can.  That's what distinguishes a loan from a gift.

Comment: Give an example.

Comment: Could you clarify - are you asking whether the company can forcibly retrieve the debt due on the card (e.g. by just taking it out of your current account or something), or just whether they can cancel the card (i.e. prevent further use) ?

Comment: @MichaelHall I could terminate the loan contract according to the contract terms, which usually includes the loan becoming liable in full at once.

Comment: @Trish another possibility is that the outstanding debt continues to be subject to the same repayment terms but that no new debt may be incurred.

Comment: Jose Garcia: I think we're all a bit confused as to whether you're talking about the authorization to borrow versus money that has actually been borrowed; that is, if you get your credit card with a $1000 limit, are they cancelling it before you bought anything or after you used the card to buy a $1000 wristwatch?

Comment: @MichaelHall That is deliberately misinterpreting what a loan means in practice. If you give me a loan that means we formed a written contract that not only specifies how much you give me but also when and how much I'm going to pay you back. In principle we could sign a contract that says you can ask for your money back at any time but no loan in the real world ever works that way and if it doesn't you can't just ask for the money back whenever you feel like it.

Comment: @quarague, I was not deliberately "misinterpreting" anything, and I know how loans work. I was being facetious to hint to the OP that the credit card company was likely acting in accordance with the terms and conditions of the loan that he agreed to. Creditors ALWAYS want their money back, it's just a matter of how much time you both agree to.  You and Trish are both offering unnecessary clarification to my pointing out of a very simple and obvious fact that was misstated in the question.

Comment: @quarague it's just the opposite of what your claiming. Most loan terms include conditions where repayment can be demanded in full, at once. For example, most home mortgages contain a clause requiring the home buyer to maintain home insurance and make their payments as scheduled. Fail to do either of those and the mortgage holder can demand full repayment at once.

Comment: @JoseGarcia regarding the deleted answer: the case was not standing in the least for what the user purported it to stand for.

Comment: @MichaelHall This user is a troll. Flag them an delete them.

Answer (score 22):

> Is it legal for Amex to close an account assuming they have no other
> legal reason and it's purely capricious behavior?

Yes. A credit card can indeed terminate a card at any time. A credit limit is not the same as a loan, and is not "money that is effectively already given to the customer."

A line of credit is a invitation to take out a loan, subject to final approval before the card holder finally makes a purchase on credit. The credit card company is entitled to change its mind until the purchase on credit is actually made by the cardholder.

Comment: "is entitled to change its mind": subject to the terms of the credit agreement.  Of course, the agreement having been drafted by the issuer, it won't likely restrict the issuer unnecessarily.  (There are surely also restrictions imposed by statute; for example, I assume that they cannot terminate the card solely for reasons of race, religion, and similar protected characteristics, but this sort of thing seems to be beyond the scope of the question.)

Comment: Just clarifying @phoog for laymen:  Any purchases already made are subject to the same conditions/interest rates as they would otherwise be.  The issuer can just decide to discontinue allowing new purchases.

Answer (score 1):

Of course they can do that. I'm sure it is all buried in the-fine-print-that-nobody-reads. But consider a few situations:

##### Regular Credit Card Usage with Problems

A customer has a credit card with a $10k limit. They routinely borrow a few hundred $ and pay it back on-time. Other times they pay the minimum due each month. No problem.

Then they *stop* paying anything. One month, no big deal. After a few months, the credit card company may decide to take some steps to make sure they (a) collect the money owed and/or (b) prevent possible larger losses. Such as:

- Lower the outstanding credit limit - i.e., allow some small purchases but not large purchases
- Cancel any future use of the card
- Turn it over to a collections department

If they just let it go at "full credit limit" until the expiration date printed on the card, they could be out a lot of money.

##### Going Out With A Bang

Someone has a credit limit of $10k. They hardly use it at all. A few hundred a month, paid back quickly. Then suddenly they want to pull out $10k at one time. The company may look at the situation and say "No", out of concern that it is either fraudulent (stolen card, etc.) or that the customer is going to try to "take the money and run". Depending on what they find initially, they may choose to cancel the card/credit limit altogether, or they may lower the limit or they may do nothing at all if they think that it was just too much at once but not an indication of fraud.

##### External Factors

When issuing a large credit line, a company may choose to get a full credit report. If that shows a certain quality of customer then they issue the credit line. Later on they may, either prompted by activity or by periodic review for other reasons, get a new credit report that shows a lower quality of customer - i.e., less likely to pay back in a timely manner. They can then choose to reduce or entirely cancel the credit limit.

Comment: This seems to have nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @JoseGarcia I am giving some typical scenarios as to *why* legal reduction or cancellation of a credit line pretty much *has* to be baked into the system in order for it to work well in the real world.

Comment: "Working in the real world" is not a legal concern.

Comment: "Working in the real world" drives a lot of the legalese in these agreements - i.e., to cover the details of all the possible ways things can (and do...) go wrong over the lifetime of a legal agreement.